# What causes this fluorescence-like effect?

Tags: optics

I have a New Year's garland that emits blue light:

[image]

When I turn it on and turn off all other lights in the room, almost all objects in the room would be colored in different shades of blue - as I would expect. However, some objects would have very bright, fluorescent-like colors, like this Rubik's cube:

[image]

Here is the same Rubik's cube in normal light:

[image]

Euro banknotes, however, do not glow in garland's light. So it doesn't seem that my garland is somehow emitting UV light...

Why does this effect happen? What is the physical mechanism behind it?

Comment: Blue light can excite green fluorescence, assuming the fluorophores absorb blue light. Likewise red and yellow fluorescence can be excited by blue or violet light: it depends on if the excitation light is absorbed in the first place.

Comment: @EdV Thanks! I didn't know that fluorescence can be caused by visible light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is perfectly possible that you are exciting fluorescent states of the molecules in your Rubik’s cube. [Fluorescence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) is simply the emission of light from an excited state for a substance. Typically, fluorescent transitions occur between singlet states of a molecule, and are what we call “allowed transitions” (see [selection rules](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule)). They are so-called because they readily occur on rapid timescales due to their favorable electric dipole moment for the transition. The change in color can depend on the nature of the states that are fluorescing. If you are exciting into a high vibrational state of the electronic excited state, the molecule may transition to a lower energy state before it fluoresces. This results in the wavelength of the emitted light red shifting compared to the absorbed light, like the blue-green shift mentioned in the comments.

The “glow” that you are observing could also be [phosphorescence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence), which is a slightly different phenomenon. By contrast, phosphorescent transitions are typically “forbidden” triplet-singlet transitions that occur when a small population of the excited molecules get trapped in a triplet state via some sort of inter system crossing transition. The emission of light from these states is typically vastly slower than from singlet states due to a small electric transition dipole moment, which leads to the observed faint glow from phosphorescent objects. The way to tell would be to see how long-lived the glow is compared to the light that you are shining on it. If the flow persists for several seconds or minutes after it is no longer exposed to the light, it is like phosphorescence.